# How to apply a RenderTransform.TranslateTransform on a Grid using a Storyboard?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

In my application resources I have defined the following `Storyboard`:

`App.xaml`

```
<Storyboard x:Key="DefaultSB" Name="DefaultSB" x:Shared="false">
    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" From="100" To="-100" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.Y)" />
    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2" From="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" />
</Storyboard>
```

In my code behind I apply the `Storyboard` to a Grid Control:

```
Storyboard myStoryboard = (Storyboard)App.Current.Resources["DefaultSB"];
Storyboard.SetTarget(myStoryboard.Children.ElementAt(0) as DoubleAnimation, Editor);
Storyboard.SetTarget(myStoryboard.Children.ElementAt(1) as DoubleAnimation, Editor);
myStoryboard.Begin();
```

Now the `Opacity` change happens, but the RenderTransform is not applied. I also tried `(UIElement.RenderTransform).TranslateTransform.Y` but that didn't work either.

How can I animate the TranslateTransform?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why won't my WPF XAML Grid TranslateTransform.X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621711/why-wont-my-wpf-xaml-grid-translatetransform-x)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For me, this example works. Please note to `Grid.RenderTransform`:

`XAML`

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="TestStoryboard">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)" 
                         To="0"/>

        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" 
                         From="0"
                         To="1" />
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid Name="MyGrid"
      Background="AliceBlue">

    <Grid.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform X="50" Y="0" />
    </Grid.RenderTransform>

    <Button VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Margin="10" 
            Content="Click"
            Click="Button_Click" />
</Grid>
```

`Code-behind`

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Storyboard myStoryboard = (Storyboard)this.Resources["TestStoryboard"];
    Storyboard.SetTarget(myStoryboard.Children.ElementAt(0) as DoubleAnimation, MyGrid);
    Storyboard.SetTarget(myStoryboard.Children.ElementAt(1) as DoubleAnimation, MyGrid);
    myStoryboard.Begin();            
}
```

For more information please see:

[`MSDN: Transforms Overview`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750596%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**`Edit`**

Also you can create `TranslateTransform` and set for `RenderTransform` in code-behind like this:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Storyboard myStoryboard = (Storyboard)this.Resources["TestStoryboard"];

    TranslateTransform myTranslate = new TranslateTransform();
    myTranslate.X = 50;
    myTranslate.Y = 0; 
    MyGrid.RenderTransform = myTranslate;

    Storyboard.SetTarget(myStoryboard.Children.ElementAt(0) as DoubleAnimation, MyGrid);
    Storyboard.SetTarget(myStoryboard.Children.ElementAt(1) as DoubleAnimation, MyGrid);

    myStoryboard.Begin();            
}
```

Comment: So the conclusion is that Storyboards can only animate properties which have been explicitly set in XAML?

Comment: Also, another thing to note is that if you set the properties explicitly using the designer then you will get an additional 'TransformGroup' Element acting as a parent of the 'TranslateTransform' Element. That is what caused the problem for me!